# how to lose the "ssl is not trusted" error in ssl server setup?

Tags: c, ssl, openssl

I have a paid ssl cert from comodo. Seems to work ok with the following lines.

```
SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ctx,"crt2/my_domain_com.crt",SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);
SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ctx,"crt2/private.key",SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);
SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx, "crt2/PositiveSSLCA2.crt",NULL);
```

However when I test it on http://sslchecker.com/sslchecker I get "VENDOR SIGNED: NO SSL is not trusted"

I assume it has something to do with the AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt file that comodo included but I'm not using.  Haven't been able to find instructions anywhere on how to use this file and make the "VENDOR SIGNED: yes"

Comment: Could you verify that your server is indeed serving the expected certificate, for example by using ssldump of openssl s_client ?

Comment: yes it is serving the cert, im not getting any errors in chrome. It doesnt really matter except Id like it to be 100% perfect.